# Ruby: How to inspect the parameters of an instance method without creating a new instance?

Tags: ruby

In Ruby 1.9.2 you can inspect the parameters of any method using method(:symbol). How could I inspect the Car#initialize method without having to create a new car?

```
class Car
  def initialize(fuel_type, passenger_capacity, door = 3)
    puts "TODO"
  end
end

Car.new(nil,nil).method(:initialize).parameters
  #=> [[:req, :fuel_type], [:req, :passenger_capacity], [:opt, :door]]
```

Instance_eval didn't work:

```
Car.instance_eval { |x| p x.method(:initialize).parameters } #=> [[:rest]]
```

Comment: Which version of ruby are you using? Tried your code in 1.8.7 and got `undefined method 'parameters'`

Comment: When specifying an instance method, the common syntax is `Car#initialize` rather than `Car.initialize`, so as not to impliy the method is on the `Car` class itself.

Comment: @rocketr I am using Ruby 1.9.2. In Ruby 1.8.7 you can only call these methods on methods: ["owner", "call", "to_proc", "unbind", "arity", "receiver", "[]"]. 1.8.7 is missing the parameters method.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
Car.instance_method(:initialize).parameters
# => [[:req, :fuel_type], [:req, :passenger_capacity], [:opt, :door]]
```